# Equivalent of Array#Uniq in Ruby1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8, uniq

I posted a question earlier - [Issues with DISTINCT when used in conjunction with ORDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155516/issues-with-distinct-when-used-in-conjunction-with-order) to which I received a great answer which worked locally on my machine.  However, when I pushed it to the server the code didn't do anything to the results... I have since contacted our host provider and discovered that the version of Ruby on the server is 1.8.7

With this in mind, is anyone able to tell me how I can do the equivalent of

`@unique_results = @filtered_names.uniq { |result| result.athlete_id }`

in a way that will run on our server?

As it stands `@unique_results` is identical to `@filtered_names` and the repeat names (as described in the original post) remain in the output.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails `3.*` you can use [`Array#uniq_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by).

Otherwise you can either look into its implementation (it's pretty straightforward, click `Show source` on the page to see it) and do smth similar or just reopen `Array` class and add that `uniq_by` method yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could add [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune)'s [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) to your gem list, that includes the block for of `uniq` and a ton of other stuff. You could also cherry pick the updated `uniq` out of backports if you just want that one piece.

Answer (score 2):

One step toward mastering Ruby is to learn to extend the core classes when you need some functionality which is sufficiently general to make sense as a "core" operation. If your programming background is in less dynamic languages, this will take some getting used to. In this case I would add something like this:

```
require 'set'
module Enumerable
  def uniq(&b)
    if block_given?
      self.map(&b).to_set.to_a
    else
      self.to_set.to_a
    end
  end
end
```

It won't be as efficient as the `uniq` built in to Ruby 1.9, but it's still O(n).

Adding this to Enumerable means you can use it on things other than Arrays. If a certain enumerable class defines a more efficient version, this will not override it -- the Ruby method lookup algorithm checks first for methods defined directly in a class, before looking for methods defined in included modules.

If you use Ruby 1.8 a lot, you can add this to a file of your own personal core extensions, and use it on future projects. If you are interested, you can see some my personal core extensions at https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-core/collections.rb (these are for Ruby 1.9).